# Terminal: create bootable USB from iso

Tags: arch-linux, dd, iso, bootable, manjaro

How can I create a bootable USB stick from an iso image?

I thought `dd` should do the work, but so far I were unsuccesful.

This is what I've tried:

1. `umount /dev/sdx`
2. deleted every partition on `sdx` with `Gparted`
3. `dd if=/path/to/iso/some_file.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=1024K`

The file is a bootable BIOS update utility, but since my laptop does not have a CD/DVD drive I want to deploy this image on a USB stick.

However, when I have a look at `sdx` in `Gparted`, it tells me that it's size is 0 and no partitions have been created, although `dd` claims it has written 26MB to `/dev/sdx`.

I also tried to create a FAT32 partition (full size) with `Gparted` and then let `dd` copy onto this partition: `dd if=/path/to/iso/some_file.iso of=/dev/sdx1`. Did not work either.

The USB Stick is ok, I can write and exchange data between my laptop and computer with it. (Actually it is the same USB stick that I used to install Manjaro on my laptop before)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `gparted` remove the existing partitions from your usb, and fix the `msdos` partition table (by going to the device menu and selecting "create partition Table"). Then, create a new partition `fat32` by right clicking on the `unallocated` space and selecting new, making a primary FAT32 partition.

Next step create your bootable usb:

```
dd if=/path_to_iso_without_space.iso of=/dev/sdx
sync
```

You can add the `bs=4M` option to make it faster:

```
dd bs=4M if=/path_to_iso.iso of=/dev/sdx
```

Example: if your device is `sdb1` you should type `sdb`

```
dd if=/path_to_iso_without_space.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: So the partition table should be `msdos` by default?

Comment: Plus: is `sync` really needed? if so, why doing it in two steps? wouldn't `dd if=/path_to_iso_without_space.iso of=/dev/sdx && sync` be better?

Comment: of cource `&& sync` is better and you need to fix the Invalid MSDOS partition tables first.

Comment: Ok, so just for clarification: the partition table should be `msdos`, a `fat32` partition (primary & full size) should be created on the usb stick and it should be unmounted before using `dd`?

Comment: It is not mounted

Comment: I think you need to make the partition as bootable ( setting the bootable flag) after coping it with dd ...

Comment: what is the point of creating a partition with Gparted if the we used dd ? isn't dd going to override all partition on the disk ?

Comment: This answer can be improved by explaining why adding `bs=4M` will make it faster.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a archlinux bootable iso, you don't have to do anything special.
Just

```
dd if=somefile.iso of=/dev/sdx
```

where `sdx` is the block device like `/dev/sda` and not a partition like `/dev/sda1`.

This is possible as the iso already contains all that is needed.
If you set some partition table, it will simply has no effect, as it will be overriden by `dd`, as anything else on the target device.

Edit: You sure have to unmout any partition on that device, as they will be overriden as described before.

Edit2: The same applies to the manjaro image, according to their wiki.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know your USB device block file (such as `/dev/sdb`) and if you want to make sure you're not writing over one of your sata system drives, you can use the more secure [`bootiso utility`](https://github.com/jsamr/bootiso).

You can give your USB device name explicitly (**will fail if it is not connected through USB**):

```
bootiso -d /dev/sdb /path_to_iso_without_space.iso
```

Or let him find it for you:

```
bootiso /path_to_iso_without_space.iso
```

See it in action:

[image]