# Cannot create bootable USB for PCBSD

Tags: usb, kali-linux, bootable, pc-bsd

I've tried creating bootable for PCBSD using `dd` as [mentioned on PCBSD website documentation](https://web.pcbsd.org/docs/) and also in the [Preinstall Instruction](https://web.pcbsd.org/doc/10/html/preinstall.html#writing-to-a-usb-device). I also tried "sync"-ing as [mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278193/152971) but it doesn't seem to work. I tried booting my laptop in both legacy and UEFI mode with secure boot disabled. Currently I'm using Kali Linux and when I restart my system with my USB drive plugged in, it simply goes to GRUB menu with Kali to choose.

When I type F12 on my dell laptop to enter boot options on startup I do not see my USB drive in my boot options. Any idea?

PS : I'm also sure that the image file was properly downloaded because the same image file works fine in virtualbox.

Comment: Can you add the donwload link or the exact image file?

Comment: @GAD3R : I went to [the official website](http://www.pcbsd.org) and downloaded the desktop image(The first image among the three available images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a bootable USB for PCBSD you should use the `PCBSD10.3-RELEASE-03-31-2016-x64-USB.img` image file , it can be downloaded from [here](http://iso.cdn.pcbsd.org/10.3-RELEASE/amd64/):

```
wget http://iso.cdn.pcbsd.org/10.3-RELEASE/amd64/PCBSD10.3-RELEASE-03-31-2016-x64-USB.img
```

Then use the `dd` command as follows:

```
dd if=PCBSD10.3-RELEASE-03-31-2016-x64-USB.img of=/dev/sdx bs=1M
```

[**Edit**](https://web.pcbsd.org/download/?lang=fr):

> Please note that you must use the `.img` file to burn to a USB device on 11.0-Current TrueOS / PC-BSD. **The `.iso` image is no longer hybrid**.

Comment: Gosh! I missed the instruction that the DVD image for PCBSD is no longer hybrid. Thanks! Please state this fact in your answer for anyone to visit this post in future.